# Viewing your predicted to actual values in R for random Forest

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation

So I have a dataset that is 162 x 151:-

```
RT (seconds)    76_TI2  114_DECC    120_Lop 212_PCD
38  4.086   1.2 2.322   0
40  2.732   0.815   1.837   1.113
41  4.049   1.153   2.117   2.354
41  4.049   1.153   2.117   3.838
42  4.56    1.224   2.128   2.38
42  2.96    0.909   1.686   0.972
42  3.237   0.96    1.922   1.202
44  2.989   0.8 1.761   2.034
```

And i want to construct a random forest model on it using 10 fold cross validation, and then view the values for the predicted and the actual value for each for fold. I'm using the randomForest package. I did:-

```
> set.seed(1500)
> model <- rfcv(x,y, cv.fold=10)
```

but I've not been able to find a way of simply viewing all the predicted values obtained from each fold and the actual value that corresponds with it. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Predicted values obtained for cross-validation are stored in `model$predicted[[1]]`, observed values is `y`. If you want to look at prediction values of each fold separately you need to get information about folds split. To do this you may:

1) split folds manually and do cross-validation by yourself

2) use `caret` package

3) slightly modify `cvrf` to output this information - add `idx` to the output list

```
rfcv2 <- function (trainx, trainy, cv.fold = 5, scale = "log", step = 0.5, 
          mtry = function(p) max(1, floor(sqrt(p))), recursive = FALSE, 
          ...) 
{
  classRF <- is.factor(trainy)
  n <- nrow(trainx)
  p <- ncol(trainx)
  if (scale == "log") {
    k <- floor(log(p, base = 1/step))
    n.var <- round(p * step^(0:(k - 1)))
    same <- diff(n.var) == 0
    if (any(same)) 
      n.var <- n.var[-which(same)]
    if (!1 %in% n.var) 
      n.var <- c(n.var, 1)
  }
  else {
    n.var <- seq(from = p, to = 1, by = step)
  }
  k <- length(n.var)
  cv.pred <- vector(k, mode = "list")
  for (i in 1:k) cv.pred[[i]] <- trainy
  if (classRF) {
    f <- trainy
  }
  else {
    f <- factor(rep(1:5, length = length(trainy))[order(order(trainy))])
  }
  nlvl <- table(f)
  idx <- numeric(n)
  for (i in 1:length(nlvl)) {
    idx[which(f == levels(f)[i])] <- sample(rep(1:cv.fold, 
                                                length = nlvl[i]))
  }
  for (i in 1:cv.fold) {
    all.rf <- randomForest(trainx[idx != i, , drop = FALSE], 
                           trainy[idx != i], trainx[idx == i, , drop = FALSE], 
                           trainy[idx == i], mtry = mtry(p), importance = TRUE, 
                           ...)
    cv.pred[[1]][idx == i] <- all.rf$test$predicted
    impvar <- (1:p)[order(all.rf$importance[, 1], decreasing = TRUE)]
    for (j in 2:k) {
      imp.idx <- impvar[1:n.var[j]]
      sub.rf <- randomForest(trainx[idx != i, imp.idx, 
                                    drop = FALSE], trainy[idx != i], trainx[idx == 
                                                                              i, imp.idx, drop = FALSE], trainy[idx == i], 
                             mtry = mtry(n.var[j]), importance = recursive, 
                             ...)
      cv.pred[[j]][idx == i] <- sub.rf$test$predicted
      if (recursive) {
        impvar <- (1:length(imp.idx))[order(sub.rf$importance[, 
                                                              1], decreasing = TRUE)]
      }
      NULL
    }
    NULL
  }
  if (classRF) {
    error.cv <- sapply(cv.pred, function(x) mean(trainy != 
                                                   x))
  }
  else {
    error.cv <- sapply(cv.pred, function(x) mean((trainy - 
                                                    x)^2))
  }
  names(error.cv) <- names(cv.pred) <- n.var
  list(n.var = n.var, error.cv = error.cv, predicted = cv.pred, idx = idx)
}
```

Now you may call

```
model <- rfcv2(x,y, cv.fold=10)
model$idx  # returns the folds split.
```

Please note that `cvrf` function wasn't designed for purely cross-validation but for variable selection. Thus you perform a lot of redundant calculations.

Comment: I did all that but for some reason when I do 'model$idx' I simply get NULL

Comment: You need to call the modified function `cvrf2`, not the original one. Please see edits at the end of the answer.

Comment: Oh I see. Is there any way of returning the results so that it has the predicted vs the actual results? As what I'm getting in return at the moment is this:-

'[1]  6  2  1  5  2  3  7 10  9  6  1  7  7  9  5  2  3  7  4 10  7  1  8  2  4
 [26]  1  6  4  5  8  4  5  9  4  4  6 10  3  6  3  5  9  9  1  3  5  2  3  2 10'

Comment: Unless this is the predicted vs the actual results, in which case I have no idea what it's saying as I'm used to dealing with outcomes such as:-

'fold 1 
Observations in test set: 16 
                  7     11     12      24     33    38      52     67     72
Predicted      49.6   44.1   26.4    39.8   53.3 40.33    47.8   56.7   58.5
cvpred        575.0 -113.2  640.7 -1045.8  876.7 -5.93  2183.0 -129.7  212.6
RT..seconds.   42.0   44.0   44.0    45.0   45.0 46.00    49.0   56.0   58.0'

Comment: These are numbers of folds to which each observation belongs. Thus the string "[1] 6 2 1 5 2 3 7 10 9 6 1 7 7 9 5 2 3 7 4 10 7 1 8 2 4 ..." means that first case belongs to the 6th fold, second case to the 2nd fold and so on. Then only you need to manually collect predictions from `model$predicted[[1]]` output and calculate statistics for each fold.

Comment: I read your question again and it's still unclear what you need to obtain. Just cross-validation predictions for each case? Then these results are stored in `model$predicted[[1]]`. Please try to clarify your question.